# How to make a proper Ubuntu/Windows 8 dual-boot using the Metro Bootloader?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, bootloader, uefi

I'm the owner of a UEFI PC and I would like to make a new setup of windows 8 and ubuntu 12.10 both in x64.

I' don't know if that's possible, I've made some searches, I've followed some tutorials like [Dual boot Win8 and Ubuntu on UEFI hardware](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/11/05/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-10-on-uefi-hardware/) but it didn't work.

So what's the best partition scheme and the different steps to get the same result as the previous tutorial ?

Comment: @Aditya It sounds like you're saying this is *not* covered by the question you suggested this should be duped to, but that what the OP wants to do here simply should not be done. Is that what you meant to convey? (It's not appropriate to close questions in such situations, at least not as duplicates.)